# ES6 node async/await unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following code that worked when running against babel.  Now that I'm using harmony I get the following error:

```
let adResult = await ad.isUserValid(domainPath, password);
^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The following class function:

```
class ActiveDirectoryHelper {
    constructor(options) {
        this.config = options.config
        this.ad = null;
    }

    connect() {

        var config = {
            url: this.config.url,
            baseDN: this.config.baseDN,
            attributes: this.config.attributes
        };

        if (this.config.account.user.length > 0) {
            config.username = this.config.account.user;
            config.password = this.config.account.password;
        }

        this.ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
    }

    async isUserValid(user, password) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            this.ad.authenticate(user, password, (err, auth) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject({
                        code: 500,
                        message: "Unknown authentication error",
                        entry: {}
                    });
                }

                if (auth) {
                    resolve({
                        code: 200,
                        message: "OK",
                        entry: {
                            user: user,
                            password: password
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    reject({
                        code: 400,
                        message: "Authentication failed",
                        entry: {}
                    });

                }

            });
        });
    }
...

exports.ActiveDirectoryHelper = ActiveDirectoryHelper;
```

I use the class as follows:

```
const ad = new ActiveDirectoryHelper({
    config: adConfig
});
ad.connect();

const domainPath = domain.length > 0 ? `${domain}\\${user}` : user;
const adResult = await ad.isUserValid(domainPath, password);
```

I run the code using the following parameters:

```
node --harmony --use_strict --harmony-async-await user.js <my parameters>
```

If I take the await when calling the method:

```
const adResult = ad.isUserValid(domainPath, password);
```

then I don't have the error but it also doesnt wait till the method finishes.
I've googled the error and it seems like your only able to use await within a function that async is in.  But without await outside of the method call, it doesnt wait till its finished.  Any ideas?

Comment: which version of `node` are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you're using an old version of Node. Any version of Node 4.3  onwards should support the let keyword.

Comment: You guys are right I switched computers that I thought had the latest version 7.  Once I updated it it worked.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['await Unexpected identifier' on Node.js 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5)

Answer (score 5):

It is because you can't use `await` unless it's in an `async` function.

See this link for details:

['await Unexpected identifier' on Node.js 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5)

Comment: Got this error in an async function and couldn't figure it out.  I had an await in a `array.forEach(item => { x = await ... })` call, of course that's a function so I just had to make it async as well: `array.forEach(async item => { x = await ... })`