# 'await Unexpected identifier' on Node.js 7.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am experimenting with the `await` keyword in Node.js. I have this test script:

```
"use strict";
function x() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({a:42});
    },100);
  });
}
await x();
```

But when I run it in node I get

```
await x();
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

whether I run it with `node` or `node --harmony-async-await` or in the Node.js 'repl' on my Mac with Node.js 7.5 or Node.js 8 (nightly build).

Oddly, the same code works in the Runkit JavaScript notebook environment: https://runkit.com/glynnbird/58a2eb23aad2bb0014ea614b

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `await` only inside of `async function`s.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use `await` outside an `async` function, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Thanks to the other commenters and some other research `await` can only be used in an `async` function e.g.

```
async function x() {
  var obj = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({a:42});
    },100);
  });
  return obj;
}
```

I could then use this function as a Promise e.g.

```
x().then(console.log)
```

or in another async function.

Confusingly, the Node.js repl doesn't allow you to do

```
await x();
```

where as the RunKit notebook environment does.

Comment: There is no point in declaring `x` as `async`. Just have a normal function and have it `return` the promise as you did originally, it's shorter, more efficient, and has exactly the same result.

Comment: in haskell, they call it async monad

Comment: Yeah, callbacks are tricky. Async/Await is also a little tricky. You need to await for everything or nothing (something like that). So you have to explicitly type async and await on every function call that is asynchronous by nature.

Comment: What is point of using async if will use then below? I would understand if we can use await down below.

Answer (score 36):

As others have said, you can't call 'await' outside of an async function.
However, to get around this you can wrap the await x(); in an async function call. I.e.,

```
function x() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({a:42});
    },100);
  });
}
//Shorter Version of x():
var x = () => new Promise((res,rej)=>setTimeout(() => res({a:42}),100));

(async ()=>{
    try{
      var result = await x();
      console.log(result);
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
})();
```

This should work in Node 7.5 or above. Also works in chrome canary snippets area.

Answer (score 18):

so as suggested by others await will work inside async. So you can use the below code to avoid using then:

```
async function callX() {
    let x_value = await x();
    console.log(x_value);
}

callX();
```

Comment: thanks, forgot the async too. The error should be "Unexpected token await" since it's the await who can't be used...