# Wait for queries results

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, couchbase

I'm using the Couchbase nodeJS SDK. To make a query I must call `bucket.query("SELECT ...", function(err, rows){console.log("query's result received")})`

I would like to run queries sequentially like :

1. Run query A
2. Work on result A
3. Run query B
4. Work on result B
5. ...
6. **Continue after all results has been reveived and handle**

Or even better it could be

1. Run all queries
2. Work on results one by one as they are being reveived
3. **Continue after all results has been reveived and handle**

The point is I dont know how to wait for all the queries to be finished before continuing. I tought of promises but I'm new to nodeJS and I'm not sure I used them correctly, maybe someone could point me to the right direction ?

I saw that the async/await feature is available in node but I didn't manage to make it working either.

Any help would be apprecietate !

---

**EDIT**

I tried to use [couchbase-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchbase-promises#promises) but I still don't get the behavior I expect. Here is what I've done:

```
console.log("start");
bucket.queryAsync(N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT * FROM DATA_BUCKET WHERE type="BOOK"'))
  .then(function(rows){console.log("success")})
  .catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
console.log("end");
```

But the output shows

```
start
end
success
```

What I would like is

```
start
success
end
```

I also tried `const rows = await bucket.queryAsync("SELECT...)` but I got an `Unexpected identifier`error. I found on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5) that it means the method `queryAsync` does not have the `async` keyword.

Any idea on how I could achieve my expected behavior?
Thank's !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naivest way to do that would be to use callbacks:

```html
bucket.query('SELECT ...', function(err, rows) {
  bucket.query('SELECT ...', function(error, moreRows) {
    bucket.query('SELECT ...', function(...) {
      // sent data to client or something
    })
  })
})
```

but, this leads to the callback hell, which needs to be avoided, so you should prefer using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

there already exists a port for couchbase from callbacks to promises:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchbase-promises

this converts callbacks to this:

```
bucket.query('SELECT ....')
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(errorCallback)
```

after that you might even consider [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which would make your code even more readable:

```
try {
    const rows = await bucket.query(...)
    // do other things
catch (e) {
    // handle errors
}
```

Comment: Could you please check up my edit? I tried what you were proposing but it seems it's not working the way I was expecting.

Comment: In order to use `await` your function should be `async` that's why you got an error, also you need node 7.6+, check out the link in my answer

Comment: I have misunderstood the part about the `async` ! I tought the called function should be async but it is the calling function that should be. Thank you !

Comment: dunno about "naivest way" works great for a simple operation. not every script is used in a nuclear reactor.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) allows you to run a list of promises and wait for all fulfillments (or the first rejection). You'll have to use something like [couchbase-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchbase-promises) or promisify yourself using [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or Q, because the Couchbase SDK does not return promises.

Once you have a query returning as a promise, you can just stack up your queries in an array, and pass it to `Promise.all()`. This will return a new promise that resolves with an array of results.

```
list = [
  bucket.query("SELECT ..."),
  bucket.query("SELECT ..."),
  bucket.query("SELECT ...")
]
Promise.all(list).then(function(results){
  // results is an array
}).catch(function(err){
  // err is the first rejection encountered
})
```

If you wanted to use async/await here, you could do something like this:

```
[r1, r2, r3] = await Promise.all(list)
```

Comment: > wait for all fulfillments (or the first rejection)
Is their a way to continue on error instead of exiting at first rejection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async water fall library its best library for serialize the function one by one 
here is link [water fall library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall) it will start executing from first function and will go till last function