# unexpected identifier when using await/async in nodejs

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm getting unexpected identifier when i use async or await in nodejs. I'm on node version 8.5.0. Completely blocked on this. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
async function methodA(options) {
    rp(options)
        .then(function (body) {            
            serviceClusterData = JSON.parse(body);         
            console.log("Step 2");
            console.log("Getting cluster details from zookeeper");
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Get failed!");

        });
}

await methodA(options);
console.log("Step 3!");
```

Tried this after first answer :

```
var serviceClusterData = "";
            console.log("Step 1!");

            ////////////////////

            async function methodA(options) {
                await rp(options)
                    .then(function (body) {
                        serviceClusterData = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log("Step 2");
                        console.log("Getting cluster details from zookeeper");
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log("Get failed!");

                    });
            }

            methodA(options);
            console.log("whoops Step 3!");
```

**Still gets out of order :(
Step 1
Step 3** 
Step 2

Comment: Yes there is a way: show us your code.

Comment: Updated the question with code. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['await Unexpected identifier' on Node.js 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5)

Answer (score 5):

You can't use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) outside of an async function.

```
async function methodA(options) {
    await rp(options)
        .then(function (body) {            
            serviceClusterData = JSON.parse(body);         
            console.log("Step 2");
            console.log("Getting cluster details from zookeeper");
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Get failed!");

        });
}

methodA(options);
console.log("Step 3!");
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this now and updated question. I'm still getting out of order console.log statements. :(  @TGrif

Comment: Yes, this is the expected result order.

Comment: Is there a way i can block execution of `console.log("whoops Step 3!");` until method A completes?

Comment: @user461112 an `async` function returns a promise, so you can treat it like one: `methodA(options).then(() => console.log('Step 3!'))`

Comment: @robertklep thanks! that works. How would it work when you have two methods - similar methodA and methodB (both with async and await)

Comment: @user461112 either `Promise.all([ methodA(), methodB() ]).then(...)` (concurrently) or `methodA().then(() => methodB()).then(...)` (sequentially). Or create a new async function that calls both using `await` and call _that_ function in a similar fashion.

Comment: @robertklep : I would like to run it sequentially.. But looks like it's not working with .then. Let me update the question to show my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict'

function methodA(options) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(1)
            resolve(true);
        }, 2000);
    })
}

//Sync Declartion
async function test() {
    //Await declaration
    await methodA({});
    console.log(2);
}
test();
```

It seems there's is some syntax error in your code. Above code works in 8.5.0

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function