# NodeJS - Unexpected identifier await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I use NodeJS and try to wrap my code by async/await but everytime getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error. Here is my code:

```
async function showOff(phone) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var message = 'Hey friend, I have a new ' + phone.color + ' ' + phone.brand + ' phone';
        resolve(message);
    });
};

let message = await showOff({ color: "black", brand: "Sony" });
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What nodejs version do you use? The async support is available only in latest I guess. http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['await Unexpected identifier' on Node.js 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` can only be used inside an `async` function.

```js
function showOff(phone) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var message = 'Hey friend, I have a new ' + phone.color + ' ' + phone.brand + ' phone';
    resolve(message);
  });
};

async function phone() {
  let message = await showOff({ color: "black", brand: "Sony" });
  console.log(message);
}

phone();
```

`async` signifies which function is waiting for the responses, not the functions that perform asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

From doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used inside an async function.**

So you can simply wrap all your code in a anonymous aync function

```
(async () => {
    async function showOff(phone) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var message = 'Hey friend, I have a new ' + phone.color + ' ' + phone.brand + ' phone';
            resolve(message);
        });
    };

    let message = await showOff({ color: "black", brand: "Sony" });

    console.log(message);
})();
```

In some cases it could be a simple solution