# How to fix "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Tags: python, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to get my post method to wait until a python script has completed on a file that a user has just uploaded. I believe the problem is due to the app.post not being asynchronous but I am not sure how to make it asynchronous.

I've tried several modifications to the following code.

```
async function pythonScript(file, cb){
  try{ 
  var PythonShell = require('python-shell');


    // Use python shell
    var {PythonShell} = require('python-shell'); 
    console.log("Filename = " + File1)

    var options = {
        mode: 'text',
        args: [File1, File2, File3] 
    }; 

    PythonShell.run('pythonFile.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results[results.length-1]);
        result = results[results.length-1];
        output = result;
        console.log("output " + output);


    });
    return output;
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}


app.post('/upload', async(req, res), (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if(err){
      res.render('index', {
        msg: err
  });
} else {
  if(req.file == undefined){
    res.render('index', {
      msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
    });
  } else {
    await pythonScript(file, cb).then(res.render('index', {
        file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`,
        msg: 'File Uploaded! '+ output 
    }));

  }
  }
  });

});
```

The pythonScript method needs to be complete prior to the page rendering otherwise the 'output' variable will be empty (output is set in the pythonScript method.

Comment: You need to declare your callback to upload as async: `async (err) => { ...`.

Comment: You're still calling res.render before the pythonScript completes though. Move it below the await instead of using `then`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['await Unexpected identifier' on Node.js 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correctly calling the function asynchronously however, Python-Shell was returning a value before the function was completing. Python-Shell returns a blob/json once it is called. Therefore, when I was running it as async, it was waiting however not long enough for my function to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your callback as async to use await on them. Your correct code should be

```
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, async (err) => {
    if(err){
      res.render('index', {
        msg: err
      });
    } else {
      if(req.file == undefined) {
        res.render('index', {
          msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
        });
      } else {
        await pythonScript(file, cb).then(res.render('index', {
          file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`,
          msg: 'File Uploaded! '+ output 
        }));
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I was able to figure out that the problem is that, while my function was running Async, PythonShell will always spit out something right after ri tis run. If anyone else is having this problem, use similarly code to what I used, and to what I used, and whatever your result is that you declared in the PythonShell.run Parameters, use check when that value gets changed to a different value (I used a wait for this) this will make the function wait until the result is actually found instead of when PythonShell returns (which is not when the script Is complete)