# I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when I did define the variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

when I try to use this code:

```
var uuid = (await SuperAgent.get(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}`)).body.id;
```

I get the error:

```
        var uuid = (await SuperAgent.get(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}`)).body.id;
                      ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Even though at the top of the code file I wrote:

```
const SuperAgent = require('superagent');
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an **unexpected** identifier, not a *reference error*.

Your copy of Node.js doesn't recognise `await` as a keyword, so it treats it as a variable. You can't follow a variable with a space and then another variable.

Node.js added enabled support for `await` by default in Node.js 7.6. Upgrade to at least that version. Ideally you should upgrade to 10.16.2 LTS as that is the currently supported version.

Comment: It's a Syntax Error of which the reason of the error is that the next token shouldn't be an identifier. Also of note is that `await` is a valid identifier in script contexts (for which it's considered an identifier)

Answer (score 2):

`await` must be inside `async`
(Also this syntax is called IIFE or Immediately Involved Function Expression, if you are curious)

```
(async () => {
    var uuid = (await SuperAgent.get(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}`)).body.id
})()
```

Comment: While this is true, if that was the problem then the error message would be *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*

Comment: @Quentin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225480/await-unexpected-identifier-on-node-js-7-5

Comment: @Quentin you will get an SyntaxError in this case, even if your node version supports async / await. [repl link](https://repl.it/repls/WoozyNegativeScript)

Comment: Actually I'm not at a laptop, but I think that code which I posted here should work